No connection because in target machine is actively refusing it
Here is my code:
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain_ollama import ChatOllama
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser

llm = ChatOllama(
    model = 'llama3.2',
    temperature = 0
)

chat_template = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
    [
        ('system', "you have to give two line definition of the word given by user"),
        ('human', 'the word is {user_input}')
    ]
)

message = chat_template.format_messages(user_input = 'backlog')
llm.invoke(message)
chain = chat_template | llm | StrOutputParser()

chain.invoke({'user_input' : 'backlog'})

And it is showing connect error:
httpx.ConnectError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

How can I fix this?
I was trying to create basic word meaning chatbot using langchain.

Is Ollama actually running on the machine on which you’re executing this script?

I’m not sure what you’re talking about, given I only asked a simple question.

this means that Ollama is not running on you machine.
after Ollama pull <model name> you need to run Ollama serve
